# backup and transfer?

Tags: backup

I've been playing around with a variety of Linux distributions for a couple month now. I've come to love Ubuntu the best and have officially installed it on my primary computer.

My question though is, how do I get all my information (firefox bookmarks, usernames and passwords to various online accounts, preferred settings, etc) from the external hard drive Ubuntu installation I've been playing around with, transferred onto my newly installed Ubuntu on my computer?

PS, You guys have been a tremendous help getting me started on Linux! I'd of long since given up and gone back to windows if not for you guys! Thank you so much!

Comment: The easiest way is to copy the hidden folder ~/.mozilla to your new home folder. Or, if you boot the external one, just open FF and setup online sync. Use the same account in the newly installed Ubuntu and everything will be in sync in a matter of seconds.

Comment: I was able to create a firefox account, login to firefox on the external hard drive and sync everything I needed. I'm sure google chrome had this feature, but I never took advantage of it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd like to vot up your answer CelticWarrior and call this question resolved, but I don't know how.  There doesn't seem to be a voting area next to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to copy the hidden folder `~/.mozilla` to your new home folder. Or, if you boot the external one, just open Firefox and setup the online sync. Use the same account in the newly installed Ubuntu and everything will be in sync in a matter of seconds.